# Browserify something with an EyalAr/lwip dependency

Tags: javascript, browserify, node-modules

I have a script requiring `lwip@0.0.8` requiring as such:

`require("lwip");`

When I run browserify on the script, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/lwip_encoder' from '/Users/sihrc/Documents/sample_project/node_modules/lwip/lib'
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
    at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
    at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I checked the in the `build/Release` and found that `lwip_encoder.node` exists but not without the extension. I tried making a copy without the extension, but it turns out it's a compiled file (I think?). Is a dependency like this not 'browserify'-able because it's compiled?

Or is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, for some libraries that have compiled C code, browserify simply won't work. It just doesn't make sense. Goes to show that I shouldn't ask questions on StackOverflow this late.